# Non-isomorphic subgroups w/ same number of elements

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q: I need to give an example of two subgroups, say $H$ and $K$, which are both subgroups of $G$. I need an example which satisfies that $H\not\cong K$ even if they have the same number of elements.

A possible solution that came to mind is the Heisenberg group but I am not sure. Can someone please verify or perhaps give me a more trivial solution?

Answer (score 1):

The group $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ contains a subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ as well as a subgroup isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\times(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$, which both have 4 elements but are not isomorphic to each other. See if you can find the subgroups yourself though.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $D_4$, the group of symmetries of the square.

This group contains a 4-element subgroup generated by a horizontal flip and a vertical flip.  It also contains a 4-element subgroup generated by a quarter-turn. The two groups are not isomorphic, as only the latter has an element of order 4.

---

Consider the group $\langle \Bbb Q, +\rangle$ of rationals under addition.  It contains a subgroup $\langle\Bbb Z, +\rangle$ of integers under addition.  Both groups are countably infinite, but not isomorphic, as the latter is cyclic and the former is not.

---

Let $A$ and $B$ be any two groups of the same order, with $A$ not isomorphic to $B$.  (There are examples of every finite composite order.)  Then consider $G=A\times B$, the direct product of $A$ and $B$.  Clearly, $G$ has subgroups isomorphic to both $A$ and to $B$.